# is there any viable rust implementation of Bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core

**Request** :
I am wondering if any developer has already developed a Rust implementation of the Bitcoin protocol.

if there is any repos, post or any relevant document please share it with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew Poelstra has a rust Bitcoin library: https://github.com/apoelstra/rust-bitcoin. I don't know how complete it is though, so use at your own risk.

There's also the parity bitcoin wallet: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bitcoin which is also written in rust.